# R - Shiny widget and Leaflet not connecting

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

The [BLschool.csv](http://pastebin.com/XumeJiws) file. 
What I want to do is to change the map on the basis of the choice selected.

So, if the `A` is chosen, then the map should only show the schools with quality rating of `A`, likewise for `B`,`C`, `D`.

However, somewhere the `input$schoolqual` value isn't coming in, or the the data isn't being subset for some reason, I am getting this error :

`Error: schqual not found`

server.R

```
sc <- read.csv("BLschools.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")

shinyServer(function(input, output){


  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

  schqual <- input$schoolqual %>%
  school <- subset(sc, sc$Rateoutof4 == schqual) %>%
  leaflet(data = school) %>%
  setView(lng = -73.98928, lat = 40.75042, zoom = 10) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(~lng, ~lat), icon = greenLeafIcon, 
             popup= ~paste("<b>", as.character(school$SchoolName),"</b><br/>",
             "Rating: ", as.character(school$Rateoutof4),"<p></p>"))
  })

})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(
   titlePanel("NYC schools"),
     sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(schoolqual, choices = c("A", "B","C", "D", "E"), selected = "A", label="school quality rating")),
     mainPanel(leafletOutput("map"))
   )
 )
)
```

Please ignore the fact that the `Rateoutof4`, despite the name is in characters. I forgot to change the column name.

Comment: Remove the ` %>%` from the 2 first lines

Comment: @HubertL Removing them - the map comes up as blank, without any markers

Comment: Try to make your code run within R first (outside a shiny app), it's easier to debug

Comment: @HubertL, Yes I have done that, `schqual <- "A"` and `school <- subset(sc, sc$Rateoutof4 == schqual)` then running the app, it displays the `A` rated schools.

Comment: Did you try to click on "Open in browser" ?

Comment: @HubertL Yes i have done it all, one in viewer plane, run in external window, open in browser. No use, its the same error.

Comment: @HubertL, I get this error too  `Warning in is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'`

Comment: Maybe your csv is not read, try a `print(str(sc))` right avfter the `read.csv` and check in the console

Comment: @HubertL Nope, nothing is printed, also that error is gone (cleaned the workspace objects), it's back to `Error: schqual not found` . Is there something wrong with the way I have written ui.R? it seems like there is no value being returned from schoolqual.

Comment: just use `print()` to check the state of each variable one  by one...

Comment: @HubertL Nothing gets printed on the console! I don't know if that's how shiny works but, when I run the app, nothing gets printed in the console. [Screenshot](https://s13.postimg.org/pz5vtj1h3/Capture.png). You see even `print(str(sc))` hasn't run

Comment: if you write `print("test")` you should get **test** printed in the console. Have you had any issue running a shiny example?

Comment: Nope, no issues with any other example. @HubertL is there a chance my code here isn't (Shiny) reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a reactive expression :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  school <- reactive(subset(sc, sc$Rateoutof4 == input$schoolqual))
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = school()) %>%
    setView(lng = -73.98928, lat = 40.75042, zoom = 10) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", 
                     options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
    addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(~lng, ~lat), 
               icon = greenLeafIcon, 
               popup= ~paste("<b>", 
                             as.character(school()$SchoolName),
                             "</b><br/>",
                             "Rating: ", 
                             as.character(school()$Rateoutof4),
                             "<p></p>"))
  })
})
```

Comment: Hey! It worked, btw change `schqual` to `schoolqual` as you removed the line `schqual <- input$schoolqual `